# Cant send response from express node.js to my ajax call present in handlebars template

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to send data from server side to my ajax call, but it says net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My client side code is

```
$.ajax({
                url:'http://localhost:3000/calculateCost',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {FurnitureID: fID, FurnitureQty: fQty},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                    console.log("error");
                }
            })
```

server side code is

```
app.post('/calculateCost', urlEncodedParser, function(req, response){
    var body = req.body;
    var qstr = "SELECT Price FROM `Furniture` WHERE 1"//FurnitureID = '"+ body.FurnitureID+"'";
    con.query(qstr, function(res,err,fields){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.send({LOLOL:"lol"});
        console.log("sent");
    });
```

the jquery I used is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That error suggests your server isn't running at `localhost:3000`. Why are you using an absolute URL rather than a relative URL, understanding that may help to identify the problem?

Comment: I have tried to with relative url as well - "/calculateCost". It is not the problem, because the post request was received by the server, but it refuses to respond properly.

Comment: How do you know that the post request was received by the server? Is `localhost:3000` the same server that is serving up your HTML page?

Comment: I don't know if it explains the error but `res.send` should be `response.send`, either that or rename your two response variables to match the usual conventions.